# How to remove duplicate objects in a List<MyObject> without using any collection and loop

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Is there any way to remove duplicate element from arraylist without using any collections and loop.

Below is my program and rollNumber is unique for every student.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestJava {

    private List<Student> dataList;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        TestJava testJava=new TestJava();
        testJava.insertRecord();
        testJava.showRecords();

    }

    private void showRecords(){

        for (Student student:dataList){
            System.out.println("====================================");
            System.out.println("RollNumber : "+student.rollNumber);
            System.out.println("Name : "+student.name);
            System.out.println("Age : "+student.age);
            System.out.println("");

        }

    }

    private void insertRecord(){
        dataList=new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add(new Student(1,"Prateek",29));
        dataList.add(new Student(2,"Faisal",27));
        dataList.add(new Student(3,"Ram",24));
        dataList.add(new Student(4,"Shashank",25));

        dataList.add(new Student(1,"Prateek",29));
        dataList.add(new Student(2,"Faisal",27));
        dataList.add(new Student(3,"Ram",24));
        dataList.add(new Student(4,"Shashank",25));

    }
}

class Student{

    public int rollNumber;
    public String name;
    public int age;

    Student(int rollNumber, String name, int age) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "without using any collections"? an `ArrayList` is a collection

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Maybe he is talking about without other collections, for example, Set.

Comment: Why do you have those restriction?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher i mean other collections like set hashset map etc.

Comment: @tobias_k There is no restriction i just wanted to know can we or not if yes then how.

Answer (score 4):

You need define `equals` and `hashCode` in `Student` class first.

In Java8, you can do it by

```
list = list.stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What i need to write in equals and hasCode methods ?

Comment: @FaisalKhan Check whether two elements are equal, probably by comparing their unique `rollNumber`.